# How to restrict to 3 digits a decimal number as a constraint check (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, check-constraints

I need to use a constraint to check if a colunm value (poids) is above 0 and no more than 3 digist after the '.' (That is an exam question that I might/will be facing)

Checking the poids is above 0 is easy.

I have google-it and people were saying it is impossible on database-side as this needs to be done as format output something like that.

decimal(5,3) limits the column to 3 digits, but we can still type more than 3 digits and this is what I don't want

This is what I have so far (Only the right hand side of 'and' is missing as this where the constraint about the 3 digits limitation is going into)

```sql
create table produit (
  NP number(5),
  poids decimal (5,3),
  constraint PK_produit primary key (NP),
  constraint ck_produit_poids check (poids >= 0 and )
);
```

Comment: The requirement doesn't make sense.  If you declare the column as `decimal(5,3)`, Oracle prevents more than 3 digits of decimal precision from being stored.  If you are concerned that the value from the client will get rounded, by the time any constraint/ trigger comes in to play, that rounding will already have taken place.  So you realistically can't enforce this.  You could do something stupid and declare the column as `decimal (6,4)`, allowing 4 decimal digits, and then add a constraint that checks whether there is a non-zero 4th decimal digit but that is overcomplicated.

Comment: Plus it fails to account for the fact that the value could have been rounded and ended up at 0 (i.e. 1.23496 would get rounded to 1.2350 which would be indistinguishable from 1.235).  You could get crazier and crazier by declaring the column as `decimal(7,5)` or `decimal(17, 15)` to make that less likely but it would still be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
 constraint ck_produit_poids check 
     (poids 
  >= 0 and
  length(Substr(poids,INSTR(poids, '.' )+1,
    length(poids) )<=3
```

Comment: yes it worked my final query is   constraint ck_produit_poids check (poids  >= 0 and length(Substr(poids,INSTR(poids, '.' ) + 1, length(poids) ))<=3);

Comment: Great.. if that helped